# Error while using JAD to decompile java class

Tags: java, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, decompiler, jad

I am trying to decompile a Java class to analyze its source code using JAD tool. However, I am getting this error once I run it:

> ./jad: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++-libc6.2-2.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I am using UBUNTU 12.04, and I have an x86 architecture.

Comment: Why not use a different decompiler? JAD is not a very good decompiler anyway. I'd recommend Procyon or Krakatau depending on whether the target is obfuscated or not (disclosure:I wrote Krakatau).

Comment: Most of my colleagues advised me to use JAD. However, I am going to try Procyon as you suggested. Thank you.

Comment: @yassine93 Feel free to contact me if you have any problems.  I am the author of Procyon.